# PHP Urls, what is the best way of making sure that they are properly formatted for hrefs

Tags: php, laravel

I have found a few ways of doing it, but what is the preferred method that doesn't require changing them before saving them into the database?  I am using PHP (Laravel) and JS on the project.

Comment: what do you mean, properly formatted? unless you decree a particular format, you can't say "this is correct" and "this is incorrect". e.g. if you say "store them as relative urls", then it won't work if you're dealing with external resources, which requires absolute urls.

Comment: like www.google.com and google.com would be http://www.google.com

Comment: Are you trying to strip just www or do you want the domain name without the hostname, even if the hostname is not www?

Comment: I want it so that you can put it into an href and it works correctly (even if they entered google.com into a form).  I have found some different ways of doing it, but likely there is one way that is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `url()` helper.

`url('user/profile')` will append `user/profile` to your base url.

`url('http://www.google.com')` will not append, and will return `http://www.google.com`.